# enable flash debug on modern chrome versions

Tags: google-chrome, flash, installation

I'm trying to install the debug version of Flash player for Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84

The [current manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-content-debugger-in-google-chrome.html) suggests opening `chrome://plugins` URL, which doesn't exist in the modern versions of Google Chrome. I've seen many reports of this behavior, but haven't found any solution so far.

So. What is the up-to-date way to debug Flash on Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

**(1)** Go to: [Adobe Flash Player Support Center -
**Debug Downloads**](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html)

**(2)** Choose a download option:

**Windows** (`.exe`):
[Flash Player content debugger for Opera and Chromium based applications – PPAPI](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/28/flashplayer_28_ppapi_debug.exe).

**Mac** (`.dmg`):
[Flash Player content debugger for Opera and Chromium based applications – PPAPI](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/28/flashplayer_28_ppapi_debug.dmg)

If you installed while Chrome is open, you will be asked to restart the browser.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Works like a charm. Strange I haven't thought about this version before.